# deleting entries from db

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I recently noticed there is two different ways to delete an entry from the DB in Entity Framework.

I had originally implemented it using the following

```
db.Courses.Remove(course);
```

But then I found out that you can also do the following

```
db.Entry(course).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

Is there any difference between the two? 
The only reason I can think for me to switch to the latter would be to be more consistent in my implementation since that's the approach I use to edit entries.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: The Remove() method is just a convenient helper around the state I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods mark the entity as deleted, so the next db.SaveChanges(); removes them from the database and the context.

This article describes all ways you can add, modify and delete entities.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696174(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, thare are differences between them two.

If you set a cascade option on the model so that when customer is marked as deleted then orders that are loaded in the context are also marked for deletion.

For instance

`var customer = db.Customers.Include(c => c.Orders).First(c => c.CustomerId == 1);
db.Customers.Remove(customer); // at this point all orders in teh context are also marked as deleted.`

However when you do this

`db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Deleted;`

does not marked the orders as deleted.

Answer (score 1):

They both do roughly the same thing.

The latter merely sets the record state to deleted, the former to Detached. You still have to call to save the changes to reflect the record removal.

```
using (var context = new SchoolEntities ()) 
{
     var dpt = new Department { Name = "Mathematics", DepartmentID = 1};
     context.Entry(dpt).State = EntityState.Added;
     context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Code shown is from same resource as other answer

Comment: In both cases you need to call SaveChanges(), and in both cases they are marked as deleted (and actually deleted).